# using atomic operations on standard types

Tags: c++, gcc, atomic, compare-and-swap

Goal: I want to implement this function:

```
int atomicCAS(int* address, int compare, int val);
```

Which is a [CUDA function](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#atomiccas), but I want to implement it for CPU in C++.
It must be compatible to this API, i.e. I cannot change the type of `address`.

I assume common hardware, e.g. amd64, and a common compiler, e.g. GCC or Clang.

The corresponding C++ STL function is [`std::atomic::compare_exchange_strong`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/atomic/atomic/compare_exchange_strong/), however, that requires a `std::atomic` type, and I am not sure whether I am allowed to just do sth like:

```
((std::atomic<int>&) address)->compare_exchange_strong(...)
```

I could also use the GCC builtin function [`__atomic_compare_exchange_n`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html) but not sure if there are any caveats or what would be a good check to assert that this is valid.

Comment: @JiveDadson: I cannot change the type of `address`. It must be compatible to the function interface in my question.

Comment: You should say in the question that  you are willing to use a non-portable, non-standard feature of gcc.  There was no mention of gcc.

Comment: @JiveDadson: I don't know. Depends on the answer. I would prefer a portable of course. But if that is not possible, then the next best thing. But I mentioned GCC, where I say "I assume ...".

Comment: The C interface might be the ticket: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic/atomic_compare_exchange

Comment: @JiveDadson: The C interface is not compatible to C++. See [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60932).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there is no portable way to do this, mostly because in C++ `atomic`s can be implemented with a lock ( or in general `sizeof(T)` != `sizeof(atomic<T>)` ).

As you mentioned, you can use the GCC builtins. These are also used by `libstdc++` to implement `std::atomic<Integral>`, so whenever you need to implement an equivalent of a `std::atomic` method you can take a look at `bits/atomic_base.h`.

For `atomic::compare_exchange_strong`:

```
_GLIBCXX_ALWAYS_INLINE bool
  compare_exchange_strong(__int_type& __i1, __int_type __i2,
              memory_order __m1,
              memory_order __m2) volatile noexcept
  {
     memory_order __b2 = __m2 & __memory_order_mask;
     memory_order __b1 = __m1 & __memory_order_mask;

     __glibcxx_assert(__b2 != memory_order_release);
     __glibcxx_assert(__b2 != memory_order_acq_rel);
     __glibcxx_assert(__b2 <= __b1);

     return __atomic_compare_exchange_n(&_M_i, &__i1, __i2, 0, __m1, __m2);
  }
```

**EDIT:** Adaptation from the previous code:

```
int atomicCAS(int* address, int *compare, int val)
{
    return __atomic_compare_exchange_n(address, compare, val, 0,
                                       __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST,
                                       __ATOMIC_ACQUIRE);
}
```

Notice that `compare` is an in-out argument, on failure it will be overwritten with the current value of `*address`.
This version is equivalent to `atomic<int>::compare_exchange_strong` with default memory ordering, see on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/kcHb51).

Comment: Thanks. That is where I was already looking at. So, to make that an complete example, put `template<typename __int_type>` before it, and add `_M_i` as the first parameter, right? Rather than using `__glibcxx_assert`, probably standard `assert` is better? And then, I ideally also would like to add a static assert whether this is valid for `__int_type`? Or is `__atomic_compare_exchange_n` anyway only defined for the types where it works? Also, default params for `__m1`/`__m2` would be nice.

Answer (score -1):

`__sync_val_compare_and_swap` is probably what you are looking for